# Building FLAC in Visual Studio 2015

Tags: c++, static-libraries, build-process, visual-studio-2015, flac

I'm trying to build FLAC in VS2015 because I need it in order to build SFML for VS2015.

**First**, I got the FLAC source and installed nasm as it said I had to.
**Then**, I got the OGG lib source and built the static Win32 version, and had no errors.
**After that**, I copied the ogg's include folder in flac's include folder, and copied the static lib to where it said I had to.
I also added the nasm exe to the executable path's in vs.
Finally, when I try to build it this is what I got:

```
Error  LNK1181  cannot open input file 'D:\Programación\C++\SFML\dependencies\flac-1.3.1\objs\Release\lib\libFLAC_static.lib'   example_c_decode_file   D:\Programación\C++\SFML\dependencies\flac-1.3.1\examples\c\decode\file\LINK    1
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not exactly sure what you picked to be built, but from the error I conclude that you're trying to build the FLAC example project while not yet having built the FLAC library itself.

When I built the SFML dependencies for [my VS 2015RC build](http://nightlybuilds.ch/compiler/show/19/Visual%20Studio-2015RC-32/) - which I've been told is compatible with the release version of VS 2015 - I just built the C++ library while ignoring all the other projects.

Comment: You were right, thank you. I'll try building it myself just to learn, but if I can't I'll try your build.